# Mongodb query array elements where each matches expressionA or expressionB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to query friends with infinite scroll. I receive already loaded userIds from frontend and need to send users who are friends with authUser and not in those loaded userIds. I have following structure in my friends collection.

```
[
  {
    userIds: [111, 222],
  },
  {
    userIds: [333, 111],
  },
  {
    userIds: [111, 444],
  },
  {
    userIds: [111, 555],
  },
  {
    userIds: [111, 666],
  },
]
```

Now I want to query docs that have userIds where one of two ids matches 111 and the other is not in [555,666]. e.g. [333, 111].

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({$and:[{array:{$nin:[555,666]}},{array:{$elemMatch:{$eq:111}}}]})
```

Comment: Why $elemMatch is needed?

Comment: ok ithin one of the element be 111 and another element not be 666 or 555
, let me explain you wat all docs that have 111 or not have 555,666 ?

Comment: There can also be docs like [222, 333]. I want to query docs which have [111, \*] or [\*, 111] where * is not in [555, 666]

Comment: so in my query I said all doc have 111 as element and not 555 , 666
means [111,666],[555,111] not acceptable
[111,222] is acceptable

Comment: Yes the logic is correct. I just want to know why $elemMatch is needed. The same result is returned when using without it.
here [https://mongoplayground.net/p/73yqd_J07Ib](https://mongoplayground.net/p/73yqd_J07Ib)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236837/discussion-between-han-moe-htet-and-mohammad-naimi).